# Lost power supply while flashing SONOFF S20

Tags: esp8266, sonoff

Yesterday I successfully flashed three out of four S20 v2.1.0 devices with ESPHome firmware. While flashing the fourth one, I accidently interrupted one of  the cables (most likely the power supply [3.3 V via TTL to USB adapter]) and since this the device is not recognized by the flashing tool (ESPHome Flasher) anymore.
Is there a possibilty to fix this and to flash a firmware onto the device? Could this even be the problem? How could I check what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Oh no. Sorry this happened !
I would try to erase the flash and format the file system and then try flashing it again.

See: (gotchas and the upgrading firmware pieces)
https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flash/

Comment: Actually the problem is solved because (at least) one solder spot was broken (this was not visible, I just refreshed all of them preventive). But you link is although very interesting, thanks for that! BTW I never had so much trouble soldering solder spots as I had with the Sonoff platine. It was almost impossible to make the solder hold on the spots...